# How to export two component simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to export two components in same time. Here one component is class component and the other  one is stateless component. I want to show the stateless component inside the class component too. So how can i export these two together and meanwhile I need to render the TabMenu(stateless component) inside the Menu(Class component) component.

```
class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      products: [],
      username: ""
    };
 }

...
   render() {

     const card = this.state.products.map(product => (
        <Card>
         ..
         </Card>
        ))
        return (


            {card}

        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.iconContainer}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Cart")}
      >
        <Image
          style={styles.icon}
          source={require("../.././res/cart2.png")}
        />
        <View style={styles.cartItems}>
          <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>1</Text>
        </View>    
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </View>
  );
 }
}

 const TabMenu = createBottomTabNavigator(
 {
      BUY: {
        screen: Menu,
        navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Image
           style={styles.tabIcon}
           source={require("../.././res/buy.png")}
            tintColor={tintColor}/> )}}

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setOrder })(TabMenu,Menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one default export which you declare and You can only pass one Component to connect .

what you can do is

```
export const TabMenu = () => {}
```

or

```
const TabMenu = () => {}

export TabMenu
```

**AND**

```
export class Menu extends Component {}
```

or

```
class Menu extends Component {}

export Menu
```

you can access this components by

```
import {TabMenu, Menu} from './yourPage.js'
```

and to connect two components what you can do is :

```
const myConnector = connect(mapState);

export const TabManuComponent = myConnector(TabMenu);
export const MenuComponent = myConnector(Menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do :

```
const reduxTabMenu=connect(mapStateToProps, {setOrder })(TabMenu )
const reduxMenu=connect(mapStateToProps, {setOrder })(Menu )

export default { reduxTabMenu, reduxMenu}
```

then to import it you can

```
import Menu from "path"
```

and to use it

```
ReduxMenu=Menu.reduxMenu

<ReduxMenu/>
```